# Do you know the breaking changes from detox@12 to detox@13?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

[Migration guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Migration.md) is currently stuck to 12.7.0 whereas the last release is 13.2.0 and (following semver) introduces breaking changes.

For my own, I updated to the 13.1 (and before, to 12.11 too) and I got timeout (with `xxx is not defined` after init) with an app launching but closing immediatly.

I tried with `config.json` as jest example does, cleaning and building the detox cache again, cleaning my iOS build folder, coming from 10.1 to 10.2.1, reinstall latest applesimutils, nothing changes.

---

Dependencies:

- Jest: 14.x
- React Native: 0.59.8
- Detox: 13.1

---

My package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start:e2e": "REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR=E2E npm run -s start:clean",
    "build:ios:cmd": "cd ios && export RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=1 && xcodebuild -workspace Coorpacademy.xcworkspace -scheme Coorpacademy -derivedDataPath build",
    "build:iphonesimulator:debug": "REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR=E2E npm run build:ios:cmd -- -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator | xcpretty",
    "prebuild:iphonesimulator:release": "REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR=E2E npm run -s generate:bundle:ios",
    "build:iphonesimulator:release": "REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR=E2E npm run build:ios:cmd -- -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator | xcpretty",
    "build:androidemulator:debug": "cd android && export REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR=E2E && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest  -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
    "build:androidemulator:release": "cd android && export REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR=E2E && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest  -DtestBuildType=release && cd ..",
    "test:end2end:ios:debug": "npm run test:end2end:ios:debug:build && npm run test:end2end:ios:debug:test",
    "test:end2end:ios:debug:build": "detox build --configuration=ios.simulator.debug",
    "test:end2end:ios:debug:test": "detox test --configuration=ios.simulator.debug",
    "test:end2end:ios:release": "npm run test:end2end:ios:release:build && npm run test:end2end:ios:release:test",
    "test:end2end:ios:release:build": "detox build --configuration=ios.simulator.release",
    "test:end2end:ios:release:test": "detox test --configuration=ios.simulator.release",
    "test:end2end:android:debug": "npm run test:end2end:android:debug:build && npm run test:end2end:android:debug:test",
    "test:end2end:android:debug:build": "detox build --configuration=android.emulator.debug",
    "test:end2end:android:debug:test": "detox test --configuration=android.emulator.debug",
    "test:end2end:android:release": "npm run test:end2end:android:release:build && npm run test:end2end:android:release:test",
    "test:end2end:android:release:build": "detox build --configuration=android.emulator.release",
    "test:end2end:android:release:test": "detox test --configuration=android.emulator.release",
  },
  "detox": {
    "test-runner": "jest",
    "runner-config": "jest.config.e2e.js",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.simulator.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Coorpacademy.app",
        "build": "npm run build:iphonesimulator:debug",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 6"
      },
      "ios.simulator.release": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Coorpacademy.app",
        "build": "npm run build:iphonesimulator:release",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 6"
      },
      "android.emulator.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/Coorpacademy-debug.apk",
        "build": "npm run build:androidemulator:debug",
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "name": "Nexus_5X_API_19"
      },
      "android.emulator.release": {
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/Coorpacademy-release.apk",
        "build": "npm run build:androidemulator:release",
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "name": "Nexus_5X_API_19"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My metro config:

```
const createBlacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

const {REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR} = process.env;

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR === 'E2E' ? ['e2e.js', 'js'] : ['js'],
    blacklistRE: (() => {
      if (REACT_NATIVE_FLAVOR === 'STORYBOOK') {
        // this is to have fixtures embedded in storybook app
        return createBlacklist([]);
      }
    })()
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false
      }
    })
  }
};
```

My jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['unit.js', 'unit.json', 'ios.js', 'android.js', 'js', 'json'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./__e2e__/init.js'],
  reporters: ['detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter'],
  bail: true,
  verbose: true
};
```

And my init file:

```
import detox from 'detox';
import adapter from 'detox/runners/jest/adapter';
import specReporter from 'detox/runners/jest/specReporter';

import json from '../package';

const config = json.detox;

jest.setTimeout(120000);
// $FlowFixMe jest flow type is incomplete
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);
// $FlowFixMe jest flow type is incomplete
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init(config);
  global.weExpect = expect;
});

beforeEach(async function() {
  await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed over an issue, there were no breaking changes that require entries to the migration guide. A breaking changes was entered and there was the potential to disrupt a lot of working environments, and thus I deemed it safer to bump the major version and risk less users being disrupted. To make this clear, I have updated the intro section of the migration guide to state this as well.

There was a change introduced in 13.1 which caused an issue with some iOS apps. This was fixed in 13.2, so please upgrade to that version and see if it solves your issue. If not, open a bug report and provide all the required information.